# What is the correct way to use addAsyncRequestTransform in apisauce to get a token?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I need to call another API to renew a token before making a request to my own service. From Apisauce documentation:

```
api.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.load('something')
})
```

> This is great if you need to fetch an API key from storage for example.
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/apisauce

My attempt is like this:

```
api.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async() => {
   await msalService.loginSilent().then(login => {
      api.setHeader('Token', login.rawIdToken);
   });
});
```

I do receive a valid token but the request have already been sent without the token. There is obviously something I'm missing or do not understand here.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to set the token on the `request`, not on th `api`.

Comment: Thanks! Doing `request.headers.Token = login.rawIdToken;` solved it. You are welcome to add the formal solution to the problem.